# Travelling from / Travelling in from?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, vocabulary

Can you please  advise me which question would a native speaker immigration officer would ask in an airport

Where are you traveling from?     or

Where are you traveling in from?

Where are you comming from?

Where are you comming in from?

Where are you flying from?

Where are you flying in from?

Are all grammatically correct?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm interested to see what an immigration officer would ask. Would he use any of the 2 questions ?

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers, at least Americans, would say

> Where are you travelling from?

We are much less likely to say

> Where are you travelling in from?

It is not necessarily incorrect or ungrammatical to say that, but it's less common or normal. If someone said it, few people would find it odd in a real situation, because the meaning is clear.

It would often be made more polite or friendly by adding *today?/tonight?/this morning/this afternoon?* or by *please?* at the end.

We more often use *in* in expressions like *... coming in from?* or *... flying in from?*

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Just to clarify...  Is it any difference between 'travel' and ' travel in'?

Comment: I edited the answer so it's hopefully more clear.

Comment: Do you mean to just ask if there's a difference in meaning between the two sentences? If so, please edit your question instead of asking additional questions as a comment.